# Como multiplicar ou somar valores php?

Tags: php

Tenho um array com valores e uma variável que irá informar se deve ser feito uma multiplicação ou soma dos valores desse array, para fazer a soma user o [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-sum.php), agora tem alguma função para multiplicar?

fiz assim, mas gostaria de saber se tem problemas na forma que fiz e/ou se tem forma melhor para isso:

```
$arr = array(2.00, 4.10, 5.00, 1.21);

echo calcValues($arr, "+"); // 12.31
echo calcValues($arr, "*"); // 49.61

function calcValues($values, $operacao)
{   
    if($operacao == "+")
    {
        return array_sum($values);
    }
    else
    {
        $res = 1;
        foreach ($values as $v) {
            $res *= $v;
        }
        return $res;
    }        
}
```

Comment: A resposta foi de encontro ao que procurava?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe uma função  para isso, [`array_product`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php).

Teste assim:

```
function calcValues($values, $operacao){   
    if ($operacao == "+"){
        return array_sum($values);
    }
    elseif ($operacao == "*"){
        return array_product($values);
    }
}
```

O resultado é:

```
echo calcValues($arr, "+"); // 12.31
echo calcValues($arr, "*"); // 49.61
```

#### Exemplo: http://ideone.com/i6aA9R